# Restore Azure Web Role website?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure, cloud, cloud-hosting

I published a Azure Web Role from Visual Studio and something went wrong. I think my workstation settings are wrong. Is there a way to restore an Azure website if a deployment goes wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you upgrade your Azure application, you do so by provisioning a staging environment which you can test before go-live. You can then switch the staging environment to live in a matter of seconds with no downtime. This makes the latest version live, but the previous version is still available to switch back to, until you’re comfortable that the new version is ok.

There are several ways to deploy your application, but if you adopt the approach of uploading your application to Blob Storage, and deploying from there, you can maintain a complete version history which you can revert back to if required.

Comment: I'm a fan of combining both the use of VIP (production/staging) or service DNS swaps as well as archiving of the deployment packages (in blob storage or elsewhere as makes sense).